# How to fix self intersected polygons visually, as well in QGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, polygon, qgis-3

I have same invalid polygon features because of self intersection. I can make them valid by using `fix geometries` tool in QGIS 3.2. However I want to show them valid visually also. The feature is valid below but visually not, how can I fix it?

[image]

It is okay correcting this by using Python and its libraries for instance Fiona, Shapely etc.

Comment: Do you want to edit the geometry by deleting the small square that is probably a member of a multipolygon once the topology of the geometry is fixed?

Comment: Yes I want to delete or dont want to show this irregular shape. But the attribute values should'nt be affected. Because it is just for good presentation to user

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.